# Query Data from Existing SQLite Database Android

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I followed this tutorial: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ Created db with SQLite Database Browser, put db file in "assets" folder etc..

Here my db structure created using SQLite Database Browser with instructions in tutorial link;
[image: db structure]

Then i added this method to end of DataBaseHelper class;

```
public ArrayList<market> getMarkets() {

    String table = "markets";
    ArrayList<market> markets = new ArrayList<market>();
    market mrkt = new market();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        do {
            mrkt.market_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("marketid"));
            mrkt.market_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            mrkt.market_telno = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("telno"));
            mrkt.market_location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("location"));
            mrkt.market_hours = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("hours"));
            markets.add(mrkt);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return markets;
}
```

and i try to show first market's informations on textview with these lines in activity class:

```
     myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
     markets = new ArrayList<market>();

     myDbHelper.createDataBase();
     myDbHelper.openDataBase();
     markets = myDbHelper.getMarkets();

     id.setText(markets.get(0).getMarket_id());
     name.setText(markets.get(0).getMarket_name());
     telno.setText(markets.get(0).getMarket_telno());
     loc.setText(markets.get(0).getMarket_location());
     hours.setText(markets.get(0).getMarket_hours());
```

However i got logcat error:

### 04-12 23:40:24.477: E/SQLiteLog(30698): (1) no such table: markets

i checked data/data file and there is not my db file
i followed tutorial line by line but i dont know why i can not create table or sqlite database properly ?
i tried .db, .sqlite3 extensions.. if i'm wrong then what should be my db file extension ?
please help..

(note: i have cyanogenmod 11.0 on my phone)

Comment: Where are you referencing the database ?

Comment: /data/data/com.deneme/databases/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the problem but this code:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    cursor.moveToNext();
    do {
        mrkt.market_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("marketid"));
        mrkt.market_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        mrkt.market_telno = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("telno"));
        mrkt.market_location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("location"));
        mrkt.market_hours = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("hours"));
        markets.add(mrkt);
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

skips the first row of the query. With `cursor.moveToFirst()` you are already pointing to the first row in the table, but you do additional `cursor.moveToNext()` which skips the first row, and goes to the second.

Comment: i just do not want to take first row. Tutorial forces me to create that first "_id" things to work fine this sqlite db with android :/

Comment: Be careful, you are talking about a column, _id is not a row. With your code you are skipping all the data the lies in the first row of the table.

Comment: oh okay:) but still confused with: 04-12 23:40:24.482: E/AndroidRuntime(30698): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: markets (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM markets

Comment: Is your database present in the databeses folder ?

Comment: in my cyanogenmod file manager, there is not my package in the data folder :/

Comment: But you have to put it manually there, try it with the emulator with Push File command.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define a table.  I'm assuming as it wasn't in the tutorial.  This is the line and it should be after the DATABASE_NAME and DATABASE_VERSION, and before the lines to identify the columns:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "markets";
```

If you fixed it with other code, please let me know!  I've been working on somet